# SQL Server SMO: DatabaseCollection is waiting for restoring databases?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have this kind of code in my c# application:

```
foreach (Database db in server.Databases)
                {
                    if ((db.Status & DatabaseStatus.Normal) == DatabaseStatus.Normal && !db.IsSystemObject) //<---------hunging here
                        this.databases.Add(db.Name);
                }
```

I run restoring a large database on the server and run my app.
When this db still is restoring then application is stopped and waiting in the loop.
How to avoid this kind of situation? e.g. to skip restoring databases?

Comment: Are you sure that it's hanging on that line and that it's not eagerly evaluating the `Database db in server.Databases`? A simple test I suppose would be if it's able to do anything with non-restoring databases.

Comment: Yes, because I go step by step in debugger in this loop and 5 databases were added to the list but on the 6th (restoring) in hungs